# How to write an optional condition in SQL Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One is the Transaction table and the other is the PriceBook table.

```
-Transaction Table-
|ItemID |   Assortment |UnitID|
|-------|--------------|------|
|A01    |           1  |ea    |
|A02    |           1  |kg    |
|A03    |           2  |pc    |

-PriceBook Table-
|ItemID |   Assortment  |UnitID |Price|
|-------|---------------|-------|-----|
|A01    |       1       |  ea   |1.5  |
|A02    |       1       |  pc   |2.5  |
|A03    |       2       |  kg   |5    |
|A03    |       2       |  pc   |1    |
```

I want to select the price from the PriceBook table, matching with the ItemID, Assortment and UnitID with Transaction table. But the UnitID match is optional, so if there is no match with UnitID, I want to have the matching result with only ItemID and Assortment.

```
-Result Table-
|ItemID|    UnitID| Price|
|------|----------|------|
|A01   |    ea    |1.5   |
|A02   |    pc    |2.5   |
|A03   |    pc    |1     |
```

I am using LEFT OUTER Join, but when I am matching ItemID and Assortment, I am getting two rows for Item A03 (I require only one), and if I am matching with ItemID, Assortment and UnitID, I am getting null for Item A02. Following is my query.

```
select DISTINCT Tx.ItemID, Pb.UnitID, Pb.Price
    from Transaction Tx with (nolock)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PriceBook Pb With (NOLOCK)      
    ON Tx.ItemID = Pb.ItemID
    AND Tx.Assortment = Pb.Assortment
    AND Tx.UnitID = Pb.UnitID -- (This conditional should be optional)
```

How do I get my desired result?

Comment: can you please show your query ？

Comment: @Squirrel I have added it in my question

Comment: `NOLOCK` is not a magic "go-faster" button, it's a magic "give-incorrect-results" button. How do you decide which row to match if you have multiple with the same `ItemID, Assortment`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`outer apply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for rows that didn't match by more columns:

> ```
> with t(ItemID, Assortment, UnitID) as (
>   select 'A01', 1, 'ea' union all
>   select 'A02', 1, 'kg' union all
>   select 'A03', 2, 'pc'
> )
> , pr(ItemID, Assortment, UnitID, Price) as (
>   select 'A01', 1, 'ea', 1.5 union all
>   select 'A02', 1, 'pc', 2.5 union all
>   select 'A03', 2, 'kg', 5   union all
>   select 'A03', 2, 'pc', 1
> )
> select
>   t.itemid
>   , t.assortment
>   , coalesce(pr.unitid, pr2.unitid, t.unitid) as unitid
>   , coalesce(pr.price, pr2.price) as price
> from t
>   left join pr
>     on t.itemid = pr.itemid
>       and t.assortment = pr.assortment
>       and t.unitid = pr.unitid
>   outer apply (
>     select top 1 pr2.unitid, pr2.price
>     from pr as pr2
>     where t.itemid = pr2.itemid
>       and t.assortment = pr2.assortment
>       /*When no matches by unitid*/
>       and pr.itemid is null
>   ) as pr2
> ```

> ```
> itemid | assortment | unitid | price
> :----- | ---------: | :----- | ----:
> A01    |          1 | ea     |   1.5
> A02    |          1 | pc     |   2.5
> A03    |          2 | pc     |   1.0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=576eeedafff46dbbe525a58f105ea855)*

Comment: This and the other answer, both are working fine for me, but for some reason, this is returning results faster, so I'm accepting this :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a very good use-case for `apply`.  However, the best solution is really simpler than the other answers:

```
select t.ItemID, t.UnitID, pb.Price
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) pb.*
      from pb
      where pb.ItemID = t.ItemID and pb.Assortment = t.Assortment 
      order by (case when pb.UnitID = t.UnitId then 1 else 2 end)
     ) pb;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4121db9e3c5899dad7d1fa1b5087f029) is a db<>fiddle.

No window functions.  No extra joins.

Answer (score 2):

An `outer apply` together with `row_number` can give you the desired results; where multiple rows match, assign a priority based on whether the `UnitId` also matches:

```
select t.ItemID, t.UnitID, pb.Price
from t
outer apply (
    select price, UnitID, 
       Row_Number() over(order by case when pb.UnitID=t.UnitID then 1 end desc)pri
    from pb
    where pb.ItemID=t.ItemID and pb.Assortment=t.Assortment 
)pb
where pb.pri=1
```

See [example DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5a6ca6f85473a7ad43d69d63eb1d40b3)

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query

```
select distinct t1.ItemID,
       case when t2.UnitID IS NULL then t1.UnitID else t2.UnitID end as UnitID,
       case when t2.Price IS NULL then t1.Price else t2.Price end as Price
from
    (select DISTINCT Tx.ItemID, Pb.UnitID, Pb.Price
    from [Transaction] Tx 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PriceBook Pb     
    ON Tx.ItemID = Pb.ItemID
    AND Tx.Assortment = Pb.Assortment) t1

join 

   (select DISTINCT Tx.ItemID, Pb.UnitID, Pb.Price
    from [Transaction] Tx 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PriceBook Pb     
    ON Tx.ItemID = Pb.ItemID
    AND Tx.Assortment = Pb.Assortment
    AND Tx.UnitID = Pb.UnitID) t2
ON t1.ItemID = t2.ItemID
```

Comment: I think this will not show the Item A02, since you are using INNER JOIN and the subquery t2 has a join condition for matching UnitID which will be false for my item A02